# R: How to compute correlation between rows of a matrix without having to transpose it?

Tags: r

I have a big matrix and am interested in computing the correlation between the rows of the matrix. Since the `cor` method computes correlation between the columns of a matrix, I am transposing the matrix before calling `cor`. But since the matrix is big, transposing it is expensive and is slowing down my program. Is there a way to compute the correlations among the rows without having to take transpose?

**EDIT**: thanks for the responses. thought i'd share some findings. my input matrix is 16 rows by 239766 cols and comes from a .mat file. I wrote C# code to do the same thing using the `csmatio` library. it looks like this:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, interictal_pattern))
            {
                var reader = new MatFileReader(file);
                var mla = reader.Data[0] as MLStructure;
                convert(mla.AllFields[0] as MLNumericArray<double>, data);

                double sum = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                {
                    for (var j = i + 1; j < 16; j++)
                    {
                        sum += cor(data, i, j);
                    }
                }
                var avg = sum / 120;                
                if (++count == 10)
                {
                    var t2 = DateTime.Now;
                    var t = t2 - t1;
                    Console.WriteLine(t.TotalSeconds);
                    break;
                }
            }



        static double[][] createArray(int rows, int cols)
        {
            var ans = new double[rows][];
            for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                ans[row] = new double[cols];
            }
            return ans;
        }

        static void convert(MLNumericArray<double> mla, double[][] M)
        {
            var rows = M.Length;
            var cols = M[0].Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                    M[i][j] = mla.Get(i, j);
        }

        static double cor(double[][] M, int i, int j)
        {
            var count = M[0].Length;
            double sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < count; ctr++)
            {
                sum1 += M[i][ctr];
                sum2 += M[j][ctr];
            }
            var mu1 = sum1 / count;
            var mu2 = sum2 / count;
            double numerator = 0, sumOfSquares1 = 0, sumOfSquares2 = 0;
            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < count; ctr++)
            {
                var x = M[i][ctr] - mu1;
                var y = M[j][ctr] - mu2;
                numerator += x * y;
                sumOfSquares1 += x * x;
                sumOfSquares2 += y * y;
            }
            return numerator / Math.Sqrt(sumOfSquares1 * sumOfSquares2);
        }
```

this gave a throughput of 22.22s for 10 files or **2.22s/file**

Then I profiled my **R** code:

```
ptm=proc.time()
for(file in files)
{   
    i = i + 1;
    mat = readMat(paste(path,file,sep=""))  
    a = t(mat[[1]][[1]])

    C = cor(a)
    correlations[i] = mean(C[lower.tri(C)])

}
print(proc.time()-ptm)
```

to my surprise its running faster than C# and is giving throughput of 5.7s per 10 files or **0.6s/file** (an improvement of almost **4x**!). The bottleneck in C# is the methods inside csmatio library to parse double values from input stream.

[image]

and if i do not `convert` the csmatio classes into a `double[][]` then the C# code runs extremely slow (order of magnitude slower ~20-30s/file).

Comment: Don't build your matrix that way in the first place.  It's atypical to put a factors into rows (not just in `R`,but in general).

Comment: i can't avoid that since the raw matrix is provided by a 3rd party and i can't make them change their format.

Comment: `t` is a very efficient vectorized function. No double `apply` for loops or double `seq` wrapped in a `mapply` for loop wrapper could ever improve its performance. R is a vectorized language and thus it is not suited well for rowwise operations. Either try @BondedDust solution, or try the Rcpp package

Answer (score 4):

Seeing that this problem arises from a data input issue whose details are not stated (and only hinted at in  a comment), I will assume this is a comma-delimited file of unquoted numbers with the number of columns= Ncol. This does the transposition on input.

```
  in.mat <- matrix( scan("path/to/the_file/fil.txt", what =numeric(0), sep=","), 
                    ncol=Ncol, byrow=TRUE)

  cor(in.nmat)
```

Comment: my input is coming from a .mat file. i am using R.matlab to read mat file into R

Comment: I'm guessing the read process (presumably using `readMat` is consuming more time than the transpose.

Answer (score 2):

One dirty work-around would be to apply cor-functions row-wise and produce the correlation matrix from the results. You could try if this is any more efficient (which I doubt, though you could fine-tune it by not double computing everything or the redundant diagonal cases):

```
# Apply 2-fold nested row-wise functions
set.seed(1)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow=10)
cormat <- apply(dat, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(z) apply(dat, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(y) cor(z, y)))
cormat[1:3,1:3] # Show few first
#            [,1]         [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] 1.000000000  0.002175792  0.1559263
#[2,] 0.002175792  1.000000000 -0.1870054
#[3,] 0.155926259 -0.187005418  1.0000000
```

Though, generally I would expect the transpose to have a really, really efficient implementation, so it's hard to imagine when that would be the bottle-neck. But, you could also dig through the implementation of 'cor' function and call the correlation C-function itself by first making sure your rows are suitable. Type 'cor' in the terminal to see the implementation, which is mostly a wrapper that makes input suitable for the C-function:

```
# Row with C-call from the implementation of 'cor':
#    if (method == "pearson") 
#        .Call(C_cor, x, y, na.method, FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks. i understand this is same as solution by sven. ironically, this performs much worse so looks like taking transpose is the best bet.

Comment: Thought so :( you might want to take a look at calling the C-implementation directly though. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer`:

```
outer(seq(nrow(mat)), seq(nrow(mat)), 
      Vectorize(function(x, y) cor(mat[x , ], mat[y , ])))
```

where `mat` is the name of your matrix.

Comment: thanks. this actually turns out to be much slower than using the transpose. my matrix is 16 rows by 239766 cols.